# Shrink div width when text break into new line

Tags: html, css

I have div without width defined:

```
|                           |
|------------------         |
|some testing text|         |
|------------------         |
|                           |
```

when viewport is shrinking it looks like this:

```
|                 |
|-----------------|
|some testing     |
|text             |
|-----------------|
|                 |
```

what I need is fit div width to text after line break:

```
|                 |
|-------------    |
|some testing|    |
|text        |    |
|-------------    |
|                 |
```

I tried using javascript to change width on resize, but sometimes there hundreds of divs and its not working very well..

Comment: you need to give width to that particular **<div>**

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yeah, i saw this, maybe its not even possible..

Comment: can you post our code?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri, <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: white; font-size: 30px;">some testing teeeeeeeeeeeext</div>

Comment: im just going to say that this has potential to shrink the box until the next line break happens and then starts shrinking again, when done with javascript. do you stop there ? do you take the longest line if the text was broken 4 times ?